# create Ftp Site programatically using C# IIS6

Tags: c#, ftp, iis-6

is there a way to create FTP site as a sibling (not as a child) of the default FTP Site??? I can't find it in google, so for now I'm using scripting: iisftp /create C:\MyFolder "MySiteName"

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't remember the exact details, but hopefully this might help you get started.

I have worked on code that made a complete copy of an IIS setup from one server to another using ADSI, so I'm fairly confident in that if it's possible, you can use ADSI to do it.

Very worst case I would have thought that you should be able to do it by creating the FTP site as normal and then adjusting the [IIS Metabase Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525644%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

[Creating Sites and Virtual Directories Using ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524830)

Comment: thanks ho1... that's the way I was doing it, but using C# instead of VB... the problem is that "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root" creates the FTP site as a child of the default ftp site... i tried removing the "/1/Root" but it fired errors, so I better tried using scripting... but it will look bad if I deliver that... thanks anyway